# Flutter library/tool version mismatch after upgrading

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

We're doing a release with almost no code changes, but it’s been a few months, so lots of deprecated lib versions have triggered a pretty massive library update, which is never good, so we try to keep those changes to a minimum.

Something between VSCode, Gradle, and the Android Gradle Plugin versions on my Mac is out of sync now, and I can’t untangle what they want where.

flutter build apk doesn’t produce very informative errors, so I dropped down to:

`$ ./gradlew assembleDebug --scan`

Which, ignoring the fluff, tells me this:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':purchases_flutter'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':purchases_flutter:classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :purchases_flutter
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6.1' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6.1')
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':purchases_flutter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':purchases_flutter' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Flutter doctor is happy:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.6, on macOS 13.5.2 22G91 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0)
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.82.2)
```

I've cleared pub_cache and re-pulled all the libs.  The relevant bits of pubspec.yaml are:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=3.0.6 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  [snip]
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  purchases_flutter: ^6.1.0
```

The buildscript portion of build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
    }
}
```

My gradle-wrapper.properties file has distributionUrl pointing to 7.6.1. (Auto-generated by gradlew)

I don't see anything else referencing a gradle version, other than in VSCode itself, the Gradle for Java plugin is v3.13.3, and my current Java version is 1.8.0_221.

What I've tried:
Quite a bit that I've already forgotten, actually, but I've tried the obvious part of changing the version in my main app's build.gradle dependency to 8.0.2, but I get the same error.  If I look in /Library/Users/me/.gradle/caches, there is an 8.0.2 folder if that means anything.

I doubt that the problem is actually the purchases_flutter lib, much more likely it's something in the local environment.